# Adding UILabel to UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way where i could add a `UILabel` on top of a `UIImageView` programmatically ?

So finally there should be a label displayed on top of a Image.

Answer (score 12):

UIImageView is a subclass of UIView so you can add any UI object onto it.

```
UILabel  *xlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20)];
    xlabel.text = @"xxx";

[myImageView addSubview:xLabel];
```

Answer (score 6):

As simple as

```
[imageView addSubview:yourLabel];
```